# Prove $a,2a,\ldots,(p-1)a$ leave different remainders mod $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Say $p$ is a prime number and we have $a,2a,\ldots,(p-1)a$,
if you then take any $ a \bmod p$ in the range of our $a$s they will all have different remainders,  as long as $a$ is not $\equiv 0 \pmod{\! p}$.

I would need help in proving this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $k,m\in\{1,2,\ldots,p-1\}$.

$$ak\equiv am\pmod{\! p}\iff p\mid a(k-m)$$

Since $(a,p)=1$, by [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid's_lemma) $p\mid k-m$.

Since $k,m\in\{1,2,\ldots, p-1\}$, we must have $k=m$

Comment: Can you explain why p | a (k-m) ? I would only  see why p | ak - am.
Edit: Oh I see ... ak - am = a (k-m)

Comment: @Somebody It's because of [distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Distributive_property): $ab+ac=a(b+c)$, or in this case $ak-am=a(k-m)$. You might find the rectangle area explanation ([here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WDpAN.png)) plausible.

Comment: Okay, I understand that now, thanks. So if we go to the next step, where it's clear that p | k - m . But k and m can only have values smaller than the prime number, thus the only number that can divide p in this area is 1.  How would that work if k = m?

Comment: $p\mid k-m$ denotes "$p$ divides $k-m$", not the other way around. So $k-m=pl$ for some $l\in\Bbb Z$ must be true. Since $k-m\in[-(p-2),p-2]$ (implying $p\cdot (-1)<k-m<p\cdot 1$), we must have $k-m=p\cdot 0$.

Comment: Aha I see, I swapped it. So k-m must be a multiple of p. And since k and m are both at smaller than p you say k-m must be 0. Wouldn't that be a division by 0? p | k-m = (k-m)/p = 0/p ?

Comment: @Somebody Definition: $p\mid a\iff a=pk$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$. As you say, division by $0$ is undefined, but $0/p$ is defined, since it's division by $p$. We have $0/p=0$. Btw, it's abuse of notation to write $p\mid k-m=(k-m)/p$. But you can write $p\mid k-m$ implies $(k-m)/p$ is an integer (with the exception $0\mid 0$).

Comment: I've never heard that 0/p = 0, I mean I do believe you, but do you have any sources for this? Probably I won't get this today as it still seems quite confusing (we haven't even reached the point what k=m actually tells me), but I really appreciate your effort, thanks.

Comment: @Somebody You could use a calculator to see that. See [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%2F2). $k=m$ tells you that $ak,am$ can only leave the same remainders mod $p$ if $k=m$.

Comment: Ok, thanks mates!

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the congruence

$$ak\equiv aj\pmod p$$

by $a^{-1}$. The inverse of $a$ exists because $\Bbb Z_p$ is a field.